# Prevent ssh-keyscan from generating output

Tags: bash, cron, openssh, stdout

**Problem:**  When running the `ssh-keyscan` command in *cron* it emails me the output of `ssh-keyscan` every day.  The email simply contains the following.

```
# <hostname> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

My (simplified) cron job:

```
host=`uname -n`
SSHKey=`ssh-keyscan $host`
echo $SSHKey >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

**My question:**  How do I prevent `ssh-keyscan` from writing anything to the shell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

redirect `stderr` into `/dev/null`

```
host=`uname -n`
SSHKey=`ssh-keyscan $host 2> /dev/null`
echo $SSHKey >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Thanks, I was assuming that output was stdout not stderr and I was redirecting the wrong stream in my tests.  I appreciate your quick reply.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `\`…\`` and not `$(…)`

Comment: it has the same meaning as you can see in manual page for `bash`